# Ruby: convert integer to 32 bit binary number (or string)

Tags: ruby, binary, integer

I want to convert a number, say `1`, into a `32` bit binary number:

```
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

how can I do this to ensure the full string is of length `32`, no matter how small the number might be?

I had a `sprintf` working for `8` bit binary, but not sure how to make it `32`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`String#rjust`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-rjust):

```
1.to_s(2).rjust(32, '0')
#⇒ "00000000000000000000000000000001"
```

Answer (score 5):

[`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-25) (via `sprintf`):

```
'%032b' % 7
=> "00000000000000000000000000000111"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-pack) and [`unpack1`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-unpack1):

```
[1].pack('L>').unpack1('B*')
#=> "00000000000000000000000000000001"
```

`L` indicates 32-bit unsigned integer, `>` denotes big endian. `B` indicates bit string, `*` outputs all available bits.

This will wrap around when exceeding the 32-bit unsigned integer range:

```
[4_294_967_294].pack('L>').unpack1('B*') #=> "11111111111111111111111111111110"
[4_294_967_295].pack('L>').unpack1('B*') #=> "11111111111111111111111111111111"
[4_294_967_296].pack('L>').unpack1('B*') #=> "00000000000000000000000000000000"
[4_294_967_297].pack('L>').unpack1('B*') #=> "00000000000000000000000000000001"
```